# Как выравнять строчный элемент по центру?

Tags: html, css

Без изменения html и без участия внешнего блока, только через сам элемент. Сам элемент на всю ширину не должен быть.

```css
.open {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="open">Open</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без изменения html с условием, что элемент не должен быть на всю ширину, только так

```
.open {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```